# Шаблонизатор движка

Tags: php

Добрый день. Пишу движок на php. Хочу сделать удобный шаблонизатор для верстки. Использую .tpl файлы как в DLE. Хотелось бы узнать, как сделать такие же метки, как в DLE типа {title}, {list} и т.д.

Например, есть фаил list.tpl с определенным содержимым. Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы содержимое файла list.tpl выводилось через метку {list}?

Comment: В них очень много не нужного. А так - да, там есть что требуется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь одним из самых популярных шаблонизаторов - smarty или twig

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/\{([\\w]+)(?:[^\{\}]+)\}/', $subject, $arr_match);
```

Я Вам дал направление куда двигаться, но лучше последуйте совету [[@Barton](/users/1971/barton)](/users/1971/barton).